# REPLACE function in snowflake with no pattern match

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do below

```
select replace('abcd.efgh@Domain.com', 'Domain.com', 'ModifyDomain.com')
```

This means whenever the field value will have "@Domain.com", it should be replaced with "ModifyDomain.com".

Will the original email field value be preserved in case

1. Original email field value is NULL / BLANK ?
2. Original email field value does not contain the pattern " Domain.com " ?

Comment: Because Domain.com could possibly exist in your string without being preceded by an '@', would suggest you include that in the pattern match and replace logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Original email field value is NULL / BLANK ? Original email field

If the email field value is NULL or BLANK, it will stay as NULL or BLANK:

```
select replace( NULL, 'Domain.com', 'ModifyDomain.com'); -- returns null
```

> value does not contain the pattern " Domain.com "?

the original value will return:

```
select replace('abcd.efgh@Domain.com', 'DomainX.com', 'ModifyDomain.com');
```